# VBA compare StringArray() element with String

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a small VBA program that needs to do two different things depending on if the first word of a string is "The" or "the". So far I have this but it is not matching them.

```
Sub Venues()

 Dim masterFile As Workbook
 Set masterFile = ActiveWorkbook

 Dim venueSplitArray() As String
 Dim tempString As String
 venueSplitArray() = Split(masterFile.Sheets(Week).Cells(I, "E"))
 tempString = venueSplitArray(0)

 If StrComp(tempString = "The", 1) And StrComp(tempString = "the", 1) Then
    ''''''CODE'''''
 Else
    ''''''CODE'''''
 End If

End Sub
```

But this isnt working for me and always returns that the strings don't match.

Comment: It should NOT be `StrComp(tempString = "The", 1)`, it should instead be: `StrComp(tempString, "The", 1)` (and you'll need to make the adjustment for both `StrComp` calls).

Comment: Surely your `If` line should be **or** not **and**?

Comment: Also, you should omit the third argument `1` or set it to `0` so that it does a case sensitive comparison, and then leave out the `And....` portion of the IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to accept both "The" or "the", then use:

```
If StrComp(tempString, "The", vbTextCompare) Then
```

if you want to differentiate "The" from "the", then use:

```
If StrComp(tempString, "The", vbBinaryCompare) Then
```